# Changing speed of video

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to change the speed of a video to the duration of my choice.

So, I know what's the final duration I want, I'm just making a cross-product to use this function in the way I wanted.

The thing is, if I try to go from 8 minutes to 6 min let's say. Everything is good, the final video lasts 6 min, no error.

But, If I try too short video, like 1 or 2 min (or less), then, the result are pretty bad. Here for example, I tried to get a 13 s video. From the first point of view, looks like everything worked at that I have my 13s video, but, when we click on it, we see that it's not a 13 s video but a 1min14s one !

[image: 0.13s]
[image: Real size]

I got this for every short duration, I tried with 8min, 18min, and 58min videos, but the result is always the same.

1 min always give 5m51s video

2 min always give 11m54s video

etc etc..

I also removed all the audio part so that would not cause any more issues but it did not worked better.

```
private func speedUpVideo(url: URL, desiredDuration: Double, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL) -> Void) {
   do {
       let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
       
       guard let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else { return }
       
       let currentDuration = asset.duration.seconds
       let speedMultiplier =  desiredDuration / currentDuration
       print(speedMultiplier);
       
       let speedComposition = AVMutableComposition()
       let speedVideoTrack = speedComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
       
       speedVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
       
       let assetTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
       
       try speedVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: videoTrack, at: .zero)
       
       let newDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(assetTimeRange.duration, multiplier: speedMultiplier)

       speedVideoTrack?.scaleTimeRange(assetTimeRange, toDuration: newDuration)
       
       let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
       dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
       let date = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
       let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent("storySocial-\(date).mp4")
       let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)
       
       guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: speedComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080) else { return }
       exporter.outputURL = url as URL
       exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
       exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
       exporter.exportAsynchronously {
           switch exporter.status {
           case .completed:
               guard let url = exporter.outputURL else {
                   print("No Output URL")
                   return
               }
               completion(url)
           case .failed, .cancelled:
               print("Export failed: \(exporter.error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
           default:
               print("Export \(exporter.status.rawValue)")
           }
       }
   } catch {
       print("ERRRRROOORRRR")
   }
}
```

By the way, this function is from this SO question : [How can I change the speed of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430425/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-a-video)
and was answered by @Trevor

Answer (score 0):

The function seems really ok,
I think there might be a minimum duration that `AVAssetExportSession` can handle, especially when dealing with very high speed multipliers. If the speed change is too extreme, the export session might not be able to process the video as expected.